# 3 way switch for hallway

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I just bought my first house. I was changing out the yellow switches for flat white ones.

I took everything apart and put it back together the same way but now I'm running into issues where I either trip two breakers or the three-way switch does not work correctly. One switch works, the other switch only works with the first switch in the on position.

[image: wire voltage]

[image: box with 2 switches]

[image: box at the end of hallway]

Comment: Any one set of 3-way switches should only get power from **one** breaker. Which means either something is really, really messed up or you have two different circuits going into these boxes and more than just the one switched set of lights. You should have (but can't guess what is in each box): one cable black hot from panel + white neutral form panel, one cable of three wires (black/red/white) carrying some combination of things (there are a few different possibilities) between the two boxes and then another black/white cable going to the lights.

Comment: Was the switch in the top box a double switch (two switches on the same yoke/gang)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Discard the belief** that you "put it together the same way" if it didn't pop breakers before you started. Your symptoms indicate that you did NOT put it together the same way. Consult the *before* pictures you should have taken...

Comment: What's the age of this house? All whites joined is **highly unlikely** in an older 3-way setup, and I don't see any blue wires, as I might expect in a more recent 3-way, so odds are very high that some of those whites are travelers and used to be connected to switches. As your before pictures would show.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes the 1 switch was a combination 3way switch with 2 switches on it. I was able to hook up the single switch fine but when the 3way was hooked up one side would work and one side would not work unless the 1st switch is left in the on position.

Comment: @Ecnerwal learning experience that i should have taken photos but i didnt. It was built in 1989 there are only (5) 3 way switches in the house 2 work perfectly together, 2 in the hallway which are messed up, and a fifth in the master that i havent found what its to yet.

Comment: I am extremely confused about terminology in the voltage chart. What do "single ground" and "joined grounds" refer to? Bare plain copper wires? (the real grounds)? White wires (which are often neutral, but not always, but never ground)?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact bare copper wire. The single copper wire is not touching the grouped together bare copper wires in the wire nut. Giving different reading when touched separately.

Comment: All the bare grounds (and any green if you have any) should always be all together. Always.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact so throw it in the wire nut with the others and try again?

Comment: Yes. The ground wire going to the panel is "zeroed out". But any other grounds that are not connected to it "float" and that can produce strange - and irrelevant - readings that just confuse things.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you for the assistance. I connected the copper with the other group hooked back up the switches and we are golden. Both side work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Cut power to both breakers and verify no live wires. It is very possible for there to be 240V in this circuit. VERY dangerous to work on live. Don't.

First, count the jacketed wires. It appears there are: 1 3-wire (red-black-white), and each box has 2 2-wires (another two wire might be there, but I can't tell). (Not counting bare grounding wires). Like this:

[image]
If this is true, both boxes may be being fed power. (I can't tell, but there may be one more 2-wire in there (shown in second diagram) You have marked the ones that you believe are powered. (Be sure there is not a 4-way involved before going further. I am assuming there is not, but if there is, everything may change here.)
The 3-wire contains travelers. In this senario, the white of the 3-wire won't be needed, and will likely be tied to neutrals on both ends, or capped. The red and black will be the travelers.

If all this this is true, then there is both power in and power out in both boxes. It was probably wired something like this:

[image]

That extra white wire (3-wire) should either tie to the neutrals in both boxes, or be capped. Power in and out for both boxes will be tied together. The 'powered' side of the 3-way will tied via pigtail to the common of the 3-way switch. Red and black of the 3-wire will tie to the switch's non-common screws (which screw isn't important, just not the common or the three-way will behave badly).

The power in the other box ties together (black to black, etc). The white from the power (in and out) ties to the white on the switch leg for the light fixture. Red and black from the 3-wire go to the switch (non-common screws). The common screw of the switch goes to the black switch leg to the light fixture (should be the only wire left not attached to anything).

To identify the switch leg, check for resistive continuity (all power off) between black and white on the 2-wires.

Comment: I took a reading from all the wires and added a chart. Box 1 has a group of copper grounds in a wire nut and a single copper ground not touching the others. When checking voltage the reading would change depending on which ground i touched.